# Append Link on Radio Form Options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

Issue 1

I am new to jquery and front end in general. I am trying to change the value of a link based on which radio button is selected. When a user selects a radio button I want append the submit link with the value of the respective radio selection. It is imporant that the value changes in the event that the user selects another radio button in that selection.

i.e. If user clicks on option 1(value="sex=male") then I want the submit link to be

Issue 2

I know how to do this with jquery but I want to know the most optimal solution that ties back into issue 1. Once a user selects a radio button I want the 'order summary' to say the users selection.

Comment: Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/6HU6u/

Comment: Your fiddle contains no javascript or jquery code.

Comment: Correct - I don't know the best way to use the append function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can see is the following:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var queryString = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function () {
        $('#' + this.name).text(this.name + ': ' + this.value);
        return this.name + '=' + this.value;
    }).get().join('&');
    $('#link').attr('href', function () {
        return 'example.com/cart?' + queryString;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6HU6u/5/).

Bear in mind I've changed the `span` to an `a` (to use the native `href` property), and *also* corrected some of the HTML errors, and reduced the unnecessary HTML (all the `br` elements weren't necessary, use CSS for presentation).

References:

- [Attribute-equals ([`attribute="value"`]) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This is a very clean and elegant solution, thank you! Thank you for adding the references as well!

Comment: Actually, my explanation of `map()` was both terrible *and* inaccurate. Sigh. Deleted my previous comment; this is why I add references, the documentation (certainly for jQuery) is written far better than I can manage...

Answer (score 0):

Post your code here in SO. Please don't give just the fiddle link.

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6HU6u/3/)***

```
$('[name=sex]').change(function () {
    var sex;
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("=male") >= 0) {
        $('#sex-male').show();
        $('#sex-female').hide();
        sex = "male";
    } else {
        $('#sex-male').hide();
        $('#sex-female').show();
        sex="female"
    }
    $('#link').append("sex=" + sex + "&");
});
$('[name=duration]').change(function () {
    var duration;
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("duration=6months") >= 0) {
        $('#duration-6').show();
        $('#duration-12').hide();
        duration = 6;
    } else {
        $('#duration-6').hide();
        $('#duration-12').show();
        duration = 12;
    }
    $('#link').append("duration=" + duration + "&");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Krishna. This works for issue 2 but not for issue 1. If you select male and then female, the link appended link is example.com/cart?sex=male&sex=female& but it should be example.com/cart?sex=female

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ara47/2/)

Note that your HTML was a bit odd so I've changed it slightly. I added a hyperlink to set the href attribute on (#link) and a span to display it so that you can see what it has been set to (#linkdisplay)

the javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var sex = 'male';
    var duration= '6';
    updateSummary(sex, duration);

    $('.sex-label').hide();
    $('.duration-label').hide();

    $("input[name='sex']").click(function(){
      sex = $(this).val();
      updateLink(sex, duration);  
      updateSummary(sex, duration);
    }); 

    $("input[name='duration']").click(function(){
      duration = $(this).val();
      updateLink(sex, duration);
      updateSummary(sex, duration);
    });
});


function updateLink(sex, duration){
    $('#link').attr('href', 'example.com/cart?sex=' + sex + '&duration=' + duration);
    $('#linkdisplay').html($('#link').attr('href'));
}

function updateSummary(sex, duration){
      $('.sex-label').hide();
      $('#sex-' + sex).show();
      $('.duration-label').hide();
      $('#duration-' + duration).show();    
}
```